# How to assign query result value by column in django

Tags: mysql, django

The output of mysql query in django is shown

**views.py**

```
def result():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("select b.date, a.value from t1 a join t2 b on a.id = b.id")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    finally:
        cursor.close()
    return result
```

**result**

```
((datetime.date(2019, 4, 25), '8192'), (datetime.date(2019, 5, 25), '8192'), (datetime.date(2019, 6, 25), '8192'), (datetime.date(2019, 11, 25), '8192'))
```

I want to assign a value to a variable like this

```
x = data
y = value
```

What should I do?
Please let me know.

Comment: Did you manage you solve the issue? If so, please mark the answer as accepted so that others can reference it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple enough, you just need a single for loop:

```py
for date, value in result:
    # do something with date and value.
```